# How can I code a class constructor in a class that inherits from a base class where the base class needs a service injected?

Tags: c#, .net

Can anyone give me some advice. I am using

Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection version 5.0.1 nuget package

I have many different views that are all based on LogBase.  In logBase there are properties that are set and so I need to inject in the ConfigService:

```
public class LogViews : LogBase
{
    public LogViews()
    {
        //
    }
    //
}

public class LogBase
{
    private readonly IConfigService _configService;
    public LogBase(IConfigService configService)
    {
        _configService = configService;
        X = _configService.X;
    }
}
```

But when the code runs it gives an error here `public LogViews()` as it is trying to call the LogBase constructor which needs the configService argument.

Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this DI problem?

Comment: `public LogViews : base(new ConfigService())`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - Sorry but I'm using DI so new ConfigService() is not i think a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should define the parametrized constructor of `LogViews` which should have `IConfigService` instance being injected. The same can be passed to base constructor as shown below

```
public class LogViews : LogBase
{
    public LogViews(IConfigService configService) : base(configService)
    {
        //
    }
    //
}
```

Comment: @RichardA - it's opinion based.  Mostly people downvote if does not have clarity or already asked. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error)